# Access to undeclared static property: Config::$config["modules"] - even though it is defined and has an element named modules

Tags: php, arrays, class, properties, static

How come I get the above error when calling `Config::get('modules');` on the following class?

The function works fine if I just return `static::$config` however when I try to return it's elements I get the error, even though it's definitely defined.

```
class Config
{
    private static $config = NULL;
    private static $initialized = FALSE;

    public static function _init()
    {
        if(self::$initialized == TRUE)
        {
            return;
        }
        static::$config = $GLOBALS['config'];
        unset($GLOBALS['config']);

        var_dump(static::$config);
        static::$initialized = TRUE;
    }

    public static function get($property = '')
    {
        self::_init();
        var_dump(static::$config);

        $parts = explode('.', $property);

        $path = 'config';

        foreach($parts as $part)
        {
            $path .= '["'.$part.'"]';
        }

        return static::$$path;

    }
}
```

output of var dumps in functions and error.

```
array(3) {
  ["APP_VERSION"]=>
  string(5) "0.0.1"
  ["database"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dsn"]=>
    string(32) "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test"
    ["user"]=>
    string(4) "root"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["modules"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
array(3) {
  ["APP_VERSION"]=>
  string(5) "0.0.1"
  ["database"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dsn"]=>
    string(32) "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test"
    ["user"]=>
    string(4) "root"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["modules"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Config::$config["modules"] in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\classes\Config.php on line 37
```

Comment: PHP is looking for a variable with the name `config["modules"]`. It just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access multidimensional array using [variable variables'](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) syntax. PHP is searching for property named `$config['modules']` which does not exist. Change the last part of your `Config::get()` method from:

```
foreach($parts as $part) {
    $path .= '["'.$part.'"]';
}

return static::$$path;
```

to:

```
$data = static::$config;
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $data = $data[$part];
}

return $data;
```

and it will work like you wanted. It's not a very good approach though, it's much better to use established solutions like [Symfony's PropertyAccess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand now why it won't work with the VV syntax, and nice clean way of accessing a MD array with the loop!

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with a small comment about Symfony PropertyAccess component, I'd recommend it over the code I wrote in the answer.